# Can't access arguments of attribute from system library using source generator

Tags: c#, roslyn, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I am trying to make a source generator for mapping columns from the google bigquery api client to class properties.  I'm having trouble getting custom column names from a `ColumnAttribute` on the properties.  `ConstructorArguments` is always empty and `columnAttribute.AttributeClass` in this sample is always an `ErrorTypeSymbol`.  If I try to load that type using `compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute")` the result is always null.

```cs
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text;

namespace BigQueryMapping;

[Generator]
public class BigQueryMapperGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        // add marker attribute
        context.RegisterPostInitializationOutput(ctx =>
            ctx.AddSource("BigQueryMappedAttribute.g.cs", SourceText.From(Attribute, Encoding.UTF8)));

        // add static interface
        context.RegisterPostInitializationOutput(ctx =>
            ctx.AddSource("BigQueryMappedInterface.g.cs", SourceText.From(Interface, Encoding.UTF8)));

        // get classes
        IncrementalValuesProvider<ClassDeclarationSyntax> classDeclarations = context.SyntaxProvider
            .CreateSyntaxProvider(
                predicate: static (s, _) => s is ClassDeclarationSyntax c && c.AttributeLists.Any(),
                transform: static (ctx, _) => GetSemanticTargetForGeneration(ctx)
            )
            .Where(static m => m is not null)!;

        IncrementalValueProvider<(Compilation Compilation, ImmutableArray<ClassDeclarationSyntax>Syntaxes)>
            compilationAndClasses = context.CompilationProvider.Combine(classDeclarations.Collect());

        context.RegisterSourceOutput(compilationAndClasses,
            static (spc, source) => Execute(source.Compilation, source.Syntaxes, spc));

        static ClassDeclarationSyntax? GetSemanticTargetForGeneration(GeneratorSyntaxContext context)
        {
            var classDeclarationSyntax = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;

            foreach (var attributeListSyntax in classDeclarationSyntax.AttributeLists)
            {
                foreach (var attributeSyntax in attributeListSyntax.Attributes)
                {
                    var fullName = context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(attributeSyntax).Type?.ToDisplayString();

                    if (fullName == "BigQueryMapping.BigQueryMappedAttribute")
                        return classDeclarationSyntax;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        static void Execute(Compilation compilation, ImmutableArray<ClassDeclarationSyntax> classes,
            SourceProductionContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                if (classes.IsDefaultOrEmpty)
                    return;

                var distinctClasses = classes.Distinct();

                var classesToGenerate = GetTypesToGenerate(compilation, distinctClasses, context.CancellationToken);

                foreach (var classToGenerate in classesToGenerate)
                {
                    var result = GeneratePartialClass(classToGenerate);
                    context.AddSource($"{classToGenerate.RowClass.Name}.g.cs", SourceText.From(result, Encoding.UTF8));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var descriptor = new DiagnosticDescriptor(id: "BQD001",
                    title: "Error creating bigquery mapper",
                    messageFormat: "{0} {1}",
                    category: "BigQueryMapperGenerator",
                    DiagnosticSeverity.Error,
                    isEnabledByDefault: true);

                context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(descriptor, null, e.Message, e.StackTrace));
            }
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<ClassToGenerate> GetTypesToGenerate(Compilation compilation,
        IEnumerable<ClassDeclarationSyntax> classes,
        CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var columnAttributeSymbol =
            compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute");

        foreach (var @class in classes)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Checking class {@class}");
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(@class.SyntaxTree);
            if (semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(@class) is not INamedTypeSymbol classSymbol)
                continue;

            var info = new ClassToGenerate(classSymbol, new());
            foreach (var member in classSymbol.GetMembers())
            {
                if (member is IPropertySymbol propertySymbol)
                {
                    if (propertySymbol.DeclaredAccessibility == Accessibility.Public)
                    {
                        if (propertySymbol.SetMethod is not null)
                        {
                            var columnName = propertySymbol.Name;
                            var columnAttribute = propertySymbol.GetAttributes().FirstOrDefault(a =>
                                a.AttributeClass!.ToDisplayString() == "Column");
                            if (columnAttribute is not null)
                            {
                                if (!columnAttribute.ConstructorArguments.IsDefaultOrEmpty)
                                {
                                    var nameArg = columnAttribute.ConstructorArguments.First();
                                    if (nameArg.Value is string name)
                                    {
                                        columnName = name;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            info.Properties.Add((columnName, propertySymbol));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            yield return info;
        }
    }


    static string GeneratePartialClass(ClassToGenerate c)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append($@"// <auto-generated/>
namespace {c.RowClass.ContainingNamespace.ToDisplayString()}
{{
    public partial class {c.RowClass.Name} : BigQueryMapping.IBigQueryGenerated<{c.RowClass.Name}>
    {{
        public static {c.RowClass.Name} FromBigQueryRow(Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryRow row)
        {{
            return new {c.RowClass.Name}
            {{");

        foreach (var (columnName, property) in c.Properties)
        {
            // would like to check if key exists but don't see any sort of ContainsKey implemented on BigQueryRow
            var tempName = $"___{property.Name}";
            var basePropertyType = property.Type.WithNullableAnnotation(NullableAnnotation.None).ToDisplayString();
            if (basePropertyType.EndsWith("?"))
            {
                basePropertyType = basePropertyType.Substring(default, basePropertyType.Length - 1);
            }

            sb.Append($@"
                {property.Name} = row[""{columnName}""] is {basePropertyType} {tempName} ? {tempName} : default,");
        }

        sb.Append($@"
            }};
        }}
    }}
}}");
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private record struct ClassToGenerate(INamedTypeSymbol RowClass,
        List<(string ColumnName, IPropertySymbol Property)> Properties);

    public const string Attribute = /* lang=csharp */ @"// <auto-generated/>
namespace BigQueryMapping {
    [System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class BigQueryMappedAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
    }
}";

    public const string Interface = /* lang=csharp */ @"// <auto-generated/>
namespace BigQueryMapping {
    public interface IBigQueryGenerated<TRow> {
        static TRow FromBigQueryRow(Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryRow row) => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}";
}
```

I have tried this with both `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute` and a custom attribute injected via `context.RegisterPostInitializationOutput` to similar results.  I have also tried rewriting this to use `ISourceGenerator` instead of `IIncrementalGenerator` and gotten the same behavior.  Am wondering what I need to do to get `columnAttribute` loading correctly.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Were you able to run this under a debugger?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski yes, I have been using this to get into a debugging context with it
https://github.com/halomademeapc/BigQueryMapping/blob/main/GenerationTests/Tests.cs#L103
(was too long to put code into comment, sorry)

Comment: @halomademeapc Don't test it this way. Use the testing library (`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SourceGenerators.Testing.MSTest` (or NUnit or XUnit)) instead.

Comment: A possible problem is inability to find CorLib types (e.g, `System.Attribute`, `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute`, etc) affecting the analysis of the compiler for your code. The testing library should do the right thing automatically for you.

Comment: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SourceGenerators.Testing.XUnit seems to want microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp at version 3 but incremental generators are on v4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to psychic debug the code but this does jump out:

> ```
>                         var columnAttribute = propertySymbol.GetAttributes().FirstOrDefault(a =>
>                            a.AttributeClass!.ToDisplayString() == "Column");
> ```

I'd guess the class here would be the fully qualified name. You already fetched the ColumnAttribute type earlier, so what'd be even better is to compare the AttributeClass to that type rather than doing string checks like this.

As a semi-related comment, if you're looking for types/members that are annotated with a specific attribute, rather than doing it yourself we have [SyntaxValueProvider.ForAttributeWithMetadataName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.syntaxvalueprovider.forattributewithmetadataname?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.3.0) which is pretty heavily optimized to reduce the performance impact on your Visual Studio. It requires 17.3 or higher, but as long as you're OK with that it'll generally help performance.

Comment: I will look at that that method, thanks.  It just shows up as "Column" when I'm inspecting using the debugger.  When I was trying it using my own custom attribute that's getting injected, the fully-qualified name did show up there but all the parameters were still empty

Comment: If you didn't have the attribute present, then we would have made a fake "error symbol" that was just named Column, since we had no other idea what it should be.

Comment: it does load that type correctly when I create the context this way
```
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("compilation",
            new[] { syntaxTree },
            new[] { MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(ColumnAttribute).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location) },
            new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication));
```
`compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(typeof(ColumnAttribute).FullName)` gets me the type as well but when I try to grab those attributes they are still `ErrorType System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute`

Comment: At this point, grab the compilation, call GetDiagnostics() and take a look at it. Something makes me think your input compilation is broken (missing a reference, using, etc.)

Comment: sir you are a gentleman and a scholar! it wanted a bunch of references to some system assemblies.  everything is loading and I can access that constructor argument

Comment: if you could add a note to your answer for anyone looking at this in the future, I will mark it as the resolution.  thanks much!!